# Is there a way to make django administration customize the models schema

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I would like to know if it's possible to customize django-admin panel so the admin can add attributes to a specific Model. change the name of attribute. Modifying the schema via the admin panel.

Comment: The database structure is not something you should modify from the frontend, as views and services rely on it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is like models where the admin can update the model attributes. Like adding new attributes, renaming a model's attributes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let users customize forms so that they can save attributes you did not initially think about, then you should create a generic `CustomField` model which could look like this:

```
class CustomField(models.Model):
    model_class = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

You would then need a way to store and retrieve the values, and this could be done with an other model like this

```
class CustomFieldValue(models.Model):
    custom_field = models.ForeignKey(CustomField)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()
    field_value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Of course retrieving the extra fields, rendering them in the form retrieving and saving the data would be completely your job. But once you have programmed the necessary methods you could add and configure new fields from django admin.

You might incur into performance problems and / or need different type of fields (float, date etc...). In that case you would need a more complex approach.